# Why does this OneToOneField reverse relationship not persist to the database?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

*Relevant frameworks: Django, Django REST Framework*

On `POST` everything seems fine: a `201 Created` response is returned and the JSON representation of what *should* have been persisted to the database in the response body is correct.

In reality, the reverse relationship between `Flag` and `Product` has not been established (see relevant models, serializer, and view below) and `Product.flag` is actually `None` (serialized to `null` by DRF).

Relevant models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    ...
    flag = models.OneToOneField('Flag', null=True, blank=True, related_name='product')

class Flag(models.Model):
    ...
    reasons = ManyToManyField('FlagReason')
    severity = models.CharField(...)
    notes = models.TextField(...)
    ...
```

Relevant DRF serializer:

```
class FlagSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = models.Flag
        fields = ('id', 'reasons', 'notes', 'created_timestamp',
                  'modified_timestamp', 'severity', 'product',)
```

Relevant DRF view:

```
class FlagListCreate(generics.ListCreateAPIView):
    queryset = Flag.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FlagSerializer
    filter_fields = ('severity',)
```

`POST` request JSON body:

```
{
    "product": 1328,
    "severity": "mid",
    "reasons": [1, 2],
    "notes": "Test note",
}
```

`201 Created` response to the above POST request (note `product` pk):

```
{
    "id": 31,
    "reasons": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "notes": "Test note",
    "created_timestamp": "2018-04-30T11:54:50.762054+01:00",
    "modified_timestamp": "2018-04-30T11:54:50.762084+01:00",
    "severity": "mid",
    "product": 1328
}
```

Response to `GET` request for above Flag (note `product` value is `null`):

```
{
    "id": 31,
    "reasons": [
        1,
        2
    ],
    "notes": "Test note",
    "created_timestamp": "2018-04-30T11:54:50.762054+01:00",
    "modified_timestamp": "2018-04-30T11:54:50.762084+01:00",
    "severity": "mid",
    "product": null
}
```

Comment: what does it showing in your admin page? is there product set to this instance of model?

Comment: @BakhromRakhmonov I'm not using the admin for this project, but at the actual database level (inspected with the shell), the above product's `flag` field is set to `None`.

Comment: This should work, but you might need to declare the related field explicitly in the FlagSerializer and set `read_only` to False.

Comment: try to add field `product = serializers.PrimaryKeyRelatedField(queryset=Product.objects.all())` in serializer `FlagSerializer`

Comment: @AnjaneyuluBatta have tried this already unfortunately and even explicitly set `read_only` to False as @DanieldRoseman suggests. The result is the same. Am considering just overriding the `create()` method entirely but it seems strange that this isn't handled automatically.

Comment: @DanielRoseman if you had to guess, d'you feel something's going wrong at the model or the serializer level? As the `201` response shows what the serializer *thinks* has been created, surely there must be some disconnect at the models layer? Though I don't show it above, I do enforce a `full_clean()` in every model's `save()` method - could that somehow be the cause?